# Triggers as Callbacks in jQuery UI Widgets

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, jquery-ui-widget-factory, event-triggers

I am working on my first jQuery UI Widget.  It uses $.ajax to pull data then populates elements after the data is loaded.  Normally I would have a function that does the ajax pull and pass an "onSuccess" callback function to that function to be executed when the ajax pull was successful.

Here is a really simplified version of what I mean:

```
function doAjax(onSuccess) {
    $.ajax({
        success: function (data) {
            onSuccess(data);
        }
    });
}

doAjax(function (data) {console.log(data);});
```

With the widget factory, I know that I can add a trigger in the $.ajax's on success function.  Can I use that trigger inside my widgets code?

Something like this works but doesn't seem like it would be the best practice:

```
_create: function() {
    self.options.dataLoaded = function (e, data) {console.log(data);};
    this._doAjax();
},
_doAjax: function() {
    var self = this;

    $.ajax({
        success: function (data) {
            self._trigger('dataLoaded', null, data);
        }
    });
}
```

What is considered best practice here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From doing some trial and error code I've determined that the first options is the best.  Here is a simplified version of the code that seems to work best.

```js
_create: function() {
    var self = this;
    self._doAjax(self.doStuff);
},
_doAjax: function(onSuccess) {
    var self = this;

    $.ajax({
        context: self,
        success: function (data) {
            onSuccess.call(this, data);
            self._trigger('dataLoaded', null, data);
        }
    });
},
doStuff: function(data) {
    var self = this;

    console.log(self);
    console.log(data);
}
```

This allows me to use a callback like I normally would and allows the user of my widget to use the `dataLoaded` event if it is needed.  The `$.ajax` `content:` option coupled with `onSuccess.call(this,data)` allows me to ensure `this` will still refer to my widget from inside the `doStuff` method that was used as the `onSuccess` callback.